# how to take index for this array

Tags: codeigniter

```
[file_1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [file] => EmailAccounts-Testing-3-customers-120email-accounts.xlsx
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [file] => application/octet-stream
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [file] => D:\wamp\tmp\phpDB76.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [file] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [file] => 21505
                )

        )
```

Comment: For uploading file  $this->upload->do_upload($field_name)

Comment: You want the Key Name or the value?

Comment: i dont want the inside array index file i want [name]=>[type]=>[tmp_name]=> like that

Comment: So you want to convert the array look like,

array(name=>data, 'type'=>data, tmp_name=>data) ???

Comment: yes sir i want that

Comment: There is no question in just code http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Or is the title the question?

Comment: `$yourArray['file_1']` by this you can access those elements. replace `$yourArray` with your respective array name.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this with Recursive:

```
  public function array_print(){


        $myArray = array(
                    'type'=>'Array outside 1',
                'name'=>'Array outside 2',
                array(
                    'file_name'=>'second array',
                    array(
                            'file_ext'=>'third array',
                        array('text'=>'Fourth array inside thrid array')
                            )
                        )           

                    );

        Print "<pre>";

        $output=array();
        $result=$this->recursive($myArray);    
        print_r($result);
        //Output value has key and value. I used ## as separator
        foreach ($result as $value) {
            $data = explode('##',$value);
            $output[$data[0]] = $data[1];
        }
        print_r($output);


  }


    function recursive($array){
        global $temp_data;

        if(!empty($array)){
        foreach($array as $key => $value){
         //If $value is an array.
            if(is_array($value)){
                //We need to loop through it.
                return $this->recursive($value);
            } else{                  
                   $temp_data[]= $key.'##'.$value;
                }
            }
        }
        return $temp_data;
    }
```

Using this we can loop through multidimensional array and store it in Global array. $myArray is your array.